# How to set Gtk.ScrolledWindow adjustment

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

How do I set the vertical adjustment for a Gtk.ScrolledWindow in python3? This is an example that demonstrates the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

class window:
    def __init__(self):
        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)
        win.set_default_size(300,100)
        scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(None, None)
        view = Gtk.Viewport(None, None)
        label = Gtk.Label('a\n\n\n\n\nb\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nc')
        view.add(label)
        scroll.add(view)
        position = Gtk.Adjustment(value=50)
        scroll.set_vadjustment(position)
        win.add(scroll)
        win.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

luciomrx's answer is correct but it is first necessary to find out the values. Therefore, it is easier to use `get_vadjustment()` and `set_value()`. Moreover the `set_vadjustment()` has to be executed after `show_all()`

This is how it works:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class window:
    def __init__(self):
        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)
        win.set_default_size(300,100)
        scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(None, None)
        view = Gtk.Viewport(None, None)
        label = Gtk.Label('a\n\n\n\n\nb\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nc')
        view.add(label)
        scroll.add(view)
        win.add(scroll)
        win.show_all()
        position = scroll.get_vadjustment()
        position.set_value(50)
        scroll.set_vadjustment(position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = window()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

usually they passed as None. if you want to adjust yourself, just make a new Gtk.Adjustment object. Gtk.Adjustment (initial val, min val, max val, step increment, page increment, page size)

Comment: Can you provide some code how to do it in the example I showed above?